# K is PD, Prove $B=K_{2}-\ell_{1}u_{1}^{T}$ is also PD

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Let K be a $n\times n$ symmetric positive definite matrix. 
Consider $K=LU$ the $LU$ decomposition of $K$.
Let $u_{1}^{T}$ be the first row of U without $u_{1,1}$ (a $1\times (n-1)$ vector), and Let $\ell_1$ be the first column of $L$ without $l_{1,1}$ (a $(n-1)\times 1$ vector).

Prove: 
$B=K_{2}-\ell_{1}u_{1}^{T}$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix. ($K_2$ is the sub matrix of $K$ without the first row and column.

My way:

I have managed to prove that $B=B^T$ and therefore $B$ is symmetric.
Now I need to show that $B$ is positive definite:

$\forall x\ne 0$: $x^TBx>0$ but I am stuck here.

Comment: Do you assume $l_{i,i} = 1$ for all $i$?

Comment: @ArinChaudhuri yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K = (\sigma_{ij})_{n \times n}$. Equating the first row and first column of $K$ with $LU$ we can easily see that 
$$\ell_{1} = \frac{1}{\sigma_{11}}\begin{pmatrix} \sigma_{21} \\ \sigma_{31} \\ \dots \\ \sigma_{n1} \end{pmatrix}$$ and $u_1 = \sigma_{11} \ell_1.$

Now you can verify the following identity
$$
B_1KB_1^{\top} = \begin{pmatrix} \sigma_{11} & \bf{0}_{1 \times (n-1)} \\ \bf{0}_{(n-1) \times 1} & B \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $B_1$ is the invertible matrix
$$
B_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \bf{0}_{1 \times (n-1)}  \\ -\ell_1 & I_{(n-1) \times (n-1)} \end{pmatrix}.$$

Since $K$ is positive definite, so is $B_1KB_1^T$ and $B$ being a principal submatrix of a positive definite matrix is also positive definite.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand how do I derive from here that $K_{2}-\ell_{1}u_{1}^{T}$  is also PD?

Comment: Apologies, I had some typos which I fixed.